# javascript: Assign method and string to the same property name

Tags: javascript, methods, properties

I know I'm going to get the people who say I simply shouldn't do this, but I am curious how people accomplish it.

I know I've seen where you can type the name of a property and get one value, but then you add the parenthesis to the end and it accesses a method.

Visually, I'm saying this:

```
foo returns 'bar'
foo() performs a function
```

The question is how?

Comment: Well where did you see it? (Maybe you're confusing it with adding properties to functions, which enables one to write `fn()` and also `fn.prop1`.)

Comment: I've been trying to remember. I've seen it a few times over the years, and now that I want to figure it out, I can't remember. :)

Comment: @doldt, you might be correct. But why would you be able to do that, and not this?

Comment: This can only be done in the special cases shown in the answers with `valueOf()` and `toString()`, it can't be done in a universal way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No, but kind of...

This can *kind* of be done with `valueOf`

```js
var foo = function() {
  console.log("From Function");
  return "Function";
};

foo.valueOf = function() {
  return "Variable";
};

alert( 'Output is: ' + foo() )
alert( 'Output is: ' + foo   )
```

**This cannot be done with JavaScript because item in an object can be two different objects.**

> If you want a property to be a function and an object, that's different

Comment: @thecodeparadox anytime, it is casted with a number / string, or really anything it still snap into it's valueOf

Comment: @thecodeparadox as vihan specified above, it is possible, due to the nature of JavaScript prototypal inheritance. When you try to convert something into a primitive type, there are several functions calling up, and one of them is valueOf() [MDN ValueOf() Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

Comment: @vihan, so a property can be a function and an object, but not a function and a string?

Comment: @AdamCook Yes, that's because everything in JavaScript is an object. So you can add a property to anything.

Comment: *"So you can add a property to anything"* - No you can't. Try `var x = 1; x.newProp = "something";` and then check the value of `x.newProp`. Not everything in JavaScript is an object. But all functions are.

Comment: @nnnnnn Everything is an Object is some form but not exactly.

Comment: @vihan I think this is moving toward the answer I'm seeking. So if I wanted to write it out (as opposed to assigning the property afterwards), how could I do that? For example, if I wrote {foo: function(){}}, how would I also add a property to that function?

Comment: @AdamCook with: `var bar = { foo: function(){} }`. You could then add: `bar.foo.valueOf = `. Perhaps getters are what you want?

Comment: @vihan I don't think getters are the answer. You've effectively answered my original question by showing that you can add properties to existing functions. I'm sure that's exactly what I've seen before. Now I'm just trying to apply this to my scenario. But I think that deserves its own SO question.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, due to how properties are resolved on objects. This is the only thing that comes remotely close:

```js
function f() {
  return 'I am being returned from the function.';
}

f.toString = function () {
  return 'I am a property on the variable.';
}

console.log('f() says: ' + f());
console.log('f says: ' + f);
```

It relies on the fact that JS typecasts functions via the .toString method in certain scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Note, workaround utilizing `setTimeout`

```js
var foo = (function() {
  var fn = function() {
    return foo && typeof foo === "string" ? function() {
      return "foobar"
    } : "bar";
  };
  setTimeout(function() {
    foo = fn()
  });
  return fn()
}());

console.log(foo); // `"bar"`

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(foo()); // `"foobar"`
});
```